# XML Parsing in SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

I have to parse the below xml query

```
DECLARE @xml    XML,
        @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

set @xml='<d><record1><columnA>1</columnA><columnB>as</columnB><columnC>ww</columnC><columnD>dw</columnD></record1>
        <record2><columnA>2</columnA><columnB>s</columnB><columnC>sd</columnC><columnD>sa</columnD></record2>
        <record3><columnA>3</columnA><columnB>asd</columnB><columnC>ad</columnC><columnD>asd</columnD></record3></d>'
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @COUNT INT, @COUNTER INT, @TQUERY   VARCHAR(2000), @SELECT  VARCHAR(MAX), @VALUES   VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE
        FROM(
            SELECT
                r.c.value( 'local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS elementName,
                r.c.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS elementValue,
                CAST(r.c.query('local-name(..)') AS VARCHAR(100)) As RowNumber
                FROM @XML.nodes('//d/record/@*') r(c)
        ) A
        select * from #TEMPTABLE
      
        DECLARE @t TABLE (AttributeName nvarchar(max), r int identity(1,1))
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
                @col nvarchar(max)

        INSERT INTO @t
        SELECT DISTINCT elementName
                --,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowNumber ORDER BY RowNumber) as r
        FROM #TEMPTABLE 

        SELECT @col = (
            SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(AttributeName)
            FROM @t
            ORDER BY r
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )

        SELECT @sql = N'
        SELECT *
        FROM #TEMPTABLE t
        PIVOT (
           min([elementValue]) FOR elementName IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
        ) as pvt'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql     
        DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLe
END
```

i need output in the table format

Comment: Please edit your post and add desired output based on the input XML.

Comment: The input XML structure is very questionable. record1, record2, etc. There is no need to have that element named as a running number. You can have it as an attribute value. Along the following: `<record id="1">`

Comment: Perhaps this works better: FROM @XML.nodes('//d/*') r(c)